# AWS EC2 policy cannot change User Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm trying to create a policy that allows changing User Data of stopped instances that have tags: "Name":"MyApp" but it only allows me to see the User Data. When I click save, it says I'm not authorised.

```
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": "ec2:*",
"Resource": "*",
"Condition": {
    "StringLike": {
      "ec2:ResourceTag/Name": "MyApp"
    }
}
```

The only way I can make it work is to remove the "Condition". However, it seems like my condition is valid. I've used my condition with other actions like: "ec2:StartInstances" and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [Actions, Resources, and Keys for EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html), the `ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute` privilege does not support any condition keys. Nor does it support any resource block. As such, you will need to grant  `ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute` to users who need to modify user data without specifying a condition key and scoped to `Resource: "*"` in order to grant this privilege.

There it appears, no supported way within AWS to get your desired configuration.

UPDATE: AWS has themselves given this same response in [the AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=304818&tstart=0).